# boosting relevance value in elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

```
settings :analysis => {           
        :analyzer => {
          :my_analyzer => {
            "tokenizer"    => "lowercase",
           # "filter"       => ["synonym", "porterStem", "phonetic"]
            "filter"       => ["synonym", "porterStem"]
          }
        },
        :filter => {
          :synonym => {
              "type" => "synonym",
              "synonyms_path" => "#{Synonym.path}"
          }
        }
      } do
mapping do
  indexes :commodity_code
  indexes :commodity_name
  indexes :long_description, boost: 1,analyzer: 'my_analyzer'
  indexes :short_description, boost: 3, analyzer: 'my_analyzer'
  indexes :manufacturer_name
  indexes :manufacturer_part_number
  indexes :increase_relevance_text
  indexes :decrease_relevance_text     
end
```

end

Configure ElasticSearch such that if the search term provided by an end user is an exact match to any of the phrases in the Increase_Relevance_Text field, then the relevance for that specific product is increased by the amount in the Increase_Relevance_Points.

Configure Elastic Search such that if the search term provided by an end user contains any of the words or phrases (but does not need to be an exact match) contained in the Decrease_Relevance_Text field, then the relevance for that specific product is decreased by the amount in the Decrease_Relevance_Points.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution i got

should do

```
           custom_score :script => "_score+doc['increase_relevance_points'].value" do
            boolean do
             should { match :increase_relevance_text, term}
            end
           end
         end
```